# how to populate a TreeView node from mouse click on in ListView in C#

Tags: c#, listview, treeview, listviewitem, treenode

I have a problem with my C# project(WinApplication). I can't populate my selected node from treeview to listview. How can I do it these; 
This is what i have done so far:

```
 List<TreeNode>checked_tree_nodes=new List<TreeNode>();

private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action != TreeViewAction.Unknown)
        {
            if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                unchecknodes(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);
            }
        }
        if (e.Action != TreeViewAction.Unknown)
       {
            if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                checknodes(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);
            }
        }
        foreach (TreeNode trl in checked_tree_nodes)
        {
            string text = "";
            ListViewItem lv = listView1.FindItemWithText(text);
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(ypoxrewseis[treeView1.SelectedNode.Index].name);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(task[treeView1.SelectedNode.Index].type);                     lvi.SubItems.Add(task[treeView1.SelectedNode.Index].date.ToString());

            if (lv == null)
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exists!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please try to decribe things slowly. Where do you click? Which data should then go from where to where?

Comment: I'm trying to make an "To do list" application and after adding an new task in treeview, if user clicks on this task, task's informations  published in listview. Also if user clicks on parent node, informations of child nodes should published in listviee

Comment: OK.  Now, what's happening in your code? Does it work, somehow? Do you reach the Add  line? Do you have nodes in the checked_tree_nodes list?

Comment: When i debug the program, when i' m clicking on the parent node, in listview shows only one child. That's my problem...